# new grunt task added to Jenkins is not found

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I am running Jenkins on Windows and grunt v0.4.1. I added a new task grunt-replace to the grunt.js however jenkins is having an issue seeing it:

```
C:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx>grunt
Local Npm module "grunt-replace" not found. Is it installed?
```

I've tried several things...

- npm install -g grunt-replace
- Restarting the jenkins service
- npm install grunt-replace
- I have installed these as the service jenkins is running under..

What am i missing here? What is the correct way to get jenkins to see the new task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whats the way you start your task? i would add grunt-replace to the `devDependencies` in your `package.json` , add your test-command to the `scripts.test-property` in your `package.json`, and then let jenkins execute that.

**package.json**

```
{
  ...some other configs
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-replace": "*",
    ... all the grunt-modules you need to be installed
  }
}
```

**jenkins excute**

```
$ npm install && npm test
```

Comment: Thats useful thanks. Turned out the issue was that i didn't check in the node_packages so each time the folder gets cleared out.